# how to expand XtraGrid's row heigth when the text length of focused cell gets its maximum length?

Tags: winforms, delegates, devexpress, xtragrid

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlPIt.png

[image: This is while I am writing text in the focused cell]

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3Xj.png
  [image: This is after I finished and pressed the TAB key, it is expanded automatically. It did because I use memo edit Repository for the editable (white) cells. And it is properties are set to wrap=yes and scrolls visible = yes]

I want to get the best fitted image which is shown on the second image on every second it needs to be wrapped. How can I do that ? I want to have the cells expanded while I write to the focused cell, not only on tab clause.

notes:

1.The columns are fixed to a certain width.
 2.I use devexpress version 10.
 3.I use windows forms c# 2.0 on .net platform.
 4.Windows Forms Application

Comment: Have you asked [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) ?

Comment: @JensKloster I have read :http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q319276.aspx and they say it is not possible. But why not? )) lets do it stackoverflow!!